# Can't change SVG innerHTML in IE

Tags: javascript, svg

I can't change the SVG code (innerHTML) of an svg using JavaScript in Internet Explorer.

If I go to inspect element on IE, and select the svg, it only has:

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" style="stroke-width: 0px;" viewBox="0 0 0 0" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" type="shape"><g /></svg>`

The code I used was:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" style="stroke-width: 0px;" viewBox="0 0 880 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" type="shape" height="400" width="880">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"/><rect x="0" y="0" width="81" height="81" fill="rgb(179,146,5)"/><rect x="560" y="160" width="81" height="81" fill="rgb(67,123,235)"/><rect x="0" y="80" width="81" height="81" fill="rgb(0,0,0)"/><rect x="80" y="80" width="81" height="81" fill="rgb(0,0,0)"/>
</svg>';
```

In Chrome (for example) it shows the svg like this:
[image: Example]

But in IE, it's just blank.

Comment: [innerHTML doesn't work on SVG elements in IE](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/Ejpgbp)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the link provided by @enxaneta created by @thebabydino,
you can use `group.textContent = 'string'` to change the content of a SVG group.
That will not make the browser render the content, so to add an SVG in a HTML element, I recommend changing the parent element's innerHTML

```js
document.querySelector('.clear').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('g').textContent = '';
});

document.querySelector('.add').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" style="stroke-width: 0px;" viewBox="0 0 880 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" type="shape" height="400" width="880"><g><rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="rgb(67,123,235)"/></g></svg>';
});
```

```html
<button class="clear">Clear</button>
<button class="add">Add</button>
<div> 
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" style="stroke-width: 0px;" viewBox="0 0 880 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" type="shape" height="400" width="880">
    <g>
      <rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="rgb(67,123,235)"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```